# pandas pivot a dataframe but preserve redundant column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm looking to pivot a dataframe but keep two columns as identifiers (each row of the dataframe will have unique values for each identifier). I can't work out how to do this through the pd.pivot function
The original dataframe is:

```
  name  code colour  price
0   B1   200    red     54
1   B2   201   blue     33
2   B3   202  green     45
```

and I want to see

```
 name code red blue green  
 B1   200  54
 B2   201      33
 B3   202           45
```

Comment: You can try `pd.concat([df[['name','code']],df.pivot(columns='colour',values='price')],1)`

Answer (score 0):

How about you use double index?

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,values='price',index=['name','code'],columns='colour')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
colour     blue  green   red
name code                   
B1   200    NaN    NaN  54.0
B2   201   33.0    NaN   NaN
B3   202    NaN   45.0   NaN
```

If you wish to have these values as columns then you can simply `reset_index()`.

```
colour name  code  blue  green   red
0        B1   200   NaN    NaN  54.0
1        B2   201  33.0    NaN   NaN
2        B3   202   NaN   45.0   NaN
```